# How to fix my merge sort?

Tags: java, arraylist, mergesort

When I compile my merge sort, it compiles fines but there is no output.

This needs to be done recursively.  Also, I do run my printList() function in my main, so it isn't that I am forgetting to print the list.  I've been staring at this for the past 30 minutes.

```
public void printList(){
    for(int i = 0; i <  fullNames.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(fullNames.get(i));
    }
}

public void sort(){
    fullNames = mergeSort(fullNames);
}

public ArrayList<String> extract(ArrayList<String> ex, int low, int high){
    ArrayList<String> answer = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = low; i <= high; i++){
        answer.add(ex.get(i));
    }

    return answer;
}

public ArrayList<String> merge(ArrayList<String> first, ArrayList<String> second){
    int f = 0; 
    int s = 0;
    ArrayList<String> answer = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(first.size() > 0 || second.size() > 0){
        if(s != second.size() && f != first.size()){
            if(first.get(f).compareTo(second.get(s)) > 0){
                answer.add(second.get(s));
                s++;
            }

            else if(first.get(f).compareTo(second.get(s)) < 0){
                answer.add(first.get(f));
                f++;
            }
        }

        else if(f == first.size()){
            while(s != second.size()){
                answer.add(second.get(s));
                s++;
            }
        }

        else{
            while(f != first.size()){
                answer.add(first.get(f));
                f++;
            }
        }
    }

    return answer;
}
public ArrayList<String> mergeSort(ArrayList<String> names){
    int k = names.size()-1;

    if(k > 1){
        ArrayList<String> first = extract(names, 0, k / 2);
        ArrayList<String> second = extract(names, (k / 2) + 1, k);

        mergeSort(first);
        mergeSort(second);

        return merge(first, second);
    }

    else{
        return names;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it with an IDE?

Comment: Is fullNames an instance variable? I'm having trouble understanding where that comes from. I copied your code into a text editor and that is the only thing I was missing an initialization for.

Comment: Check you merge method. It is getting stuck inside while loop.

Comment: Did a test here... You loop condition on merge always solver to true and the llop never stops.

Comment: Ahhh... I'm so stupid.  Can't believe I didn't notice that.  Thanks.

Comment: Now that it is working, the list is still coming out unedited.  The output is the exact same as the input.  Can anyone help fix this bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The while condition in your merge will never be false because the size of first and second is never adjusted within the loop:

```
while(first.size() > 0 || second.size() > 0){
        if(s != second.size() && f != first.size()){
            if(first.get(f).compareTo(second.get(s)) > 0){
                answer.add(second.get(s));
                s++;
            }

            else if(first.get(f).compareTo(second.get(s)) < 0){
                answer.add(first.get(f));
                f++;
            }
        }

        else if(f == first.size()){
            while(s != second.size()){
                answer.add(second.get(s));
                s++;
            }
        }

        else{
            while(f != first.size()){
                answer.add(first.get(f));
                f++;
            }
        }
    }
```